# Prove that a connected manifold is path connected.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, connectedness, path-connected

I had the following idea: to prove this by induction.

Assume that we can prove it for a one-manifold. Now take a two-manifold $M$, and embed it in $R^5$. Take two points $p,q\in M$. Then there exists a hyperplane $H$ in $R^5$ containing $p,q$ such that $H\cap M$ is a connected one-manifold. Hence, by the inductive hypothesis, we are done. For all manifold of higher dimensions $n$, we just have to ensure that there exists a hypersurface that intersects the embedded manifold such that the intersection is a connected $n-1$ manifold.

Is there a way of making this proof work?

Comment: What are your definitions of "connected manifold" and "path connected manifold"?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps that it can work, but that approach looks too much complicated. Besides, there are $2$-dimensional manifolds which cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the Klein bottle is an example).

The statement is easy to prove using the fact that manifolds are locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, together with the fact that, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, open connected sets are always path-connected.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write $R^5$, which would be true by Whitney Embedding Theorem

Comment: How do you prove it using your statement? The two points might not be in the same chart

Comment: Fix a point $p$ and let $C$ be the set of all points $q\in M$ for which there is a path in $M$ joining $p$ to $q$. Clearly, $C\neq\emptyset$, since $p\in C$. Now, it's just a matter of proving that $C$ is both closed and open in $M$.